# Selenium- Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()? Only one test in execution

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to execute written in Selenium with Junit. Its just one test. The test runs but I'm getting this failure message - 
1) testTripPlannerJUnit(com.example.tests.TripPlannerJUnit)
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?
I understand the problem is with teardown but how can i correct it.

```
package com.example.tests;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.ChromeDriverManager;
public class TripPlannerJUnit {
private WebDriver driver;
private String baseUrl;
private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
  ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
  driver = new ChromeDriver();
  baseUrl = "https://www.google.com.au/.com/";
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public void testTripPlannerJUnit() throws Exception {
driver.get("https://transportnsw.info/trip#/");
driver.findElement(By.id("search-input-From")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("search-input-From")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("search-input-From")).sendKeys("North Sydney Station");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='North Sydney Station'])[1]/following::li[1]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("search-input-To")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("search-input-To")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("search-input-To")).sendKeys("Town Hall Station");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Town Hall Station'])[1]/following::ul[1]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("search-button")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
driver.quit();
String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
  fail(verificationErrorString);
}
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}


private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
try {
  driver.findElement(by);
  return true;
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
  return false;
}
}

private boolean isAlertPresent() {
try {
  driver.switchTo().alert();
  return true;
} catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
  return false;
}
}

private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
try {
  Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
  String alertText = alert.getText();
  if (acceptNextAlert) {
    alert.accept();
  } else {
    alert.dismiss();
  }
  return alertText;
} finally {
  acceptNextAlert = true;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `@After`, you have written `driver.quit()` first and then you have a `if` condition followed by the `implicit wait` on the driver, however till the time your code reaches the implicit wait line, the driver instance has already been quit by the `driver.quit()` line.

So to correct it, please try:

```
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
fail(verificationErrorString);
   }
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.quit();
}
```

Have just moved the `driver.quit()` line to the end of the code and one more suggestion, in your `@After`, you have put an implicit wait, but you are not interacting with any webElement there, so the implicit wait line of code can be removed as it is not required.